# Export a track from QField as a .kml (from your device, for use on your device)

Tags: qgis, kml, qfield

I am new to QField. I am trying to simplify our field workers' process, which involves both digitizing new points and creating KMLs to use in other apps, like Gaia.  I like the interface in QField for the digitization, but I can't find a way to export individual layers in a way that would be usable in these other apps.  I can only figure out how to export a GeoPackage to my phone or how to sync with QGIS and get a KML there.  (Another common format like .gpx would also be fine.)